# Determining the largest volume the following cuboid can have

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

A cuboid has three of its sides in the coordinate planes and one of its corners in the first octant on the paraboloid

$$ z = 8 - 2x^2 - y^2 $$

What is the largest volume the cuboid can have?

I've solved optimization problems before, but it has always been when a function has been given. In this case there doesn't seem to be any function given, so i am completely lost.

Any hint, tip or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You asked for a function. You are trying to optimise the volume $$V=xyz$$  subject to

- $z = 8 - 2x^2 - y^2$
- $x \ge 0$,  $y \ge 0$, $z \ge 0$